# White screen after selecting something in raspi-config

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, raspicam, raspi-config

I wanted to activate the camera on my RPI 3 but in `raspi-config` when I selected the camera just a white screen appeared.

Do I just have to wait or is something wrong?

---

**UPDATE:**

I'm on Raspbian Buster, I have a Pi NoIR Camera V2, and I use `sudo` for `raspi-config`.

Comment: Hello and welcome -- Which version of Raspbian? -- Did you do that with the required permission? -- Which camera model? -- Answer these questions and add more details on the question's body.

Comment: I'm on Raspbian Buster, i have a Pi NoIR Camera V2, and I use sudo for raspi-config.

Comment: sorry for the inconviniece, I finally solved the problem myself.

Comment: Great. Please add an answer for others that may face a problem that you had.